# Wordpress How to Create a new section like comments?

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a section like comments in wordpress.for ex. user can comments on a post i need a button your views.when user will click on this than he can submit his views related to that post.Form fields will be same like comments.Is there any plugin in wordpress?I also need to show total submitted views of users and views on frontend of single post page like we show comments.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your code? It would make it all a lot easier for us to help you :)

Comment: currently i am trying to doing it as a custom post. I am inserting data as a custom post when user submit the form.

Comment: Please paste in your code, otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Hey thanks for help.i have done it by creating custom post.